# PyQt6 minimal install (Linux and Win10)

Tags: linux, windows, installation, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to prepare a distribution for my small program using PyQt6.

Problem is I cannot make any assumptions about target system besides availability of a reasonably recent version of python (i.e.: 3.9+).

I am trying to prepare a script to build the needed VENV and then to pack it using PyInstaller.

Problem is neither under Linux nor under windows this seems enough (missing .so/.dll).

Under Linux I am testing on a minimal LXD installation:

```
lxc launch images:debian/bookworm pytest
lxc exec pytest -- apt update
lxc exec pytest -- apt upgrade
lxc exec pytest -- apt install -y python3
lxc exec pytest -- apt install -y python3-venv
lxc exec pytest -- python3 -m venv venv
lxc exec pytest -- venv/bin/pip install PyQt6
lxc exec pytest -- venv/bin/python -c "from PyQt6 import QtCore"
```

Last line dies with:

```
$ lxc exec pytest -- venv/bin/python -c "from PyQt6 import QtCore"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

OTOH under Win10 I have a very similar behavior:

```
python -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade wheel setuptools
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install PyQt6
```

Installation is apparently correct, but, again:

```
venv\Scripts\python -c "from PyQt6 import QtCore"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.
```

(last sentence translates to something like "Impossible to find specified procedure")

Under Linux I know how to "fix" problem installing libs system-wide, but that's not something an "unprivileged user" could do; under Win I'm completely in thee dark as I don't even know what "procedure" wasn't found where.

What am I missing?